# Make style for single listview item (unwanted scaling)

Tags: android, listview, layout, row

Hey i wanna make specific single item row for my listView but don't know exacly how to handle it.

i.stack.imgur.com/9fUmX.png

I made something like this using weights on linear layout but it's not working correctly when additional info is too long.

i.stack.imgur.com/uG43j.png

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#55000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <!-- pomysle jeszcze nad wagami -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/JsonItemDataNumberOfTheDayFree"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="21"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/JsonItemDataMonthFree"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/JsonItemDataNumberOfTheDayFree"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="CZE"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textSize="13sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- tu nie jestem pewny margin top? -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/JsonItemTitleEventFree"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/JsonItemAdditionalInfoFree"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Additional Info"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/JsonItemDateFree"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/JsonItemLogoCategoryFree"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/category_music"
                android:scaleType="fitStart" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#55000000"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/JsonItemDataNumberOfTheDayFree"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="21"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/JsonItemDataMonthFree"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/JsonItemDataNumberOfTheDayFree"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="CZE"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:id="@+id/JsonItemTitleEventFree"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/JsonItemAdditionalInfoFree"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Additional Info"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/JsonItemDateFree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/JsonItemLogoCategoryFree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/category_music"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />
</LinearLayout>
```